# Query from an array of pfobjects

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

```
    PFQuery *fromRequests = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"FriendshipRequest"];
    [fromRequests whereKey:@"fromUser" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
    PFQuery *toRequests = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"FriendshipRequest"];
    [toRequests whereKey:@"toUser" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
    PFQuery *friendship = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:@[fromRequests, toRequests]];
    [friendship whereKey:@"status" equalTo:@"accepted"];
    [friendship includeKey:@"fromUser"];
    [friendship includeKey:@"toUser"];
    [friendship findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *friendshipObjects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {

        }
    }];
```

This is how i am getting friends of a specific user. a friendship model contains following fields:

- fromUser
- toUser
- status

and each user has a `currentLocation` field. In a separate method, i get users from this `friendshiprequest` array. So, i have an array contains a couple of `PFUser` objects. (which are friends of current user)

What i want is getting users, only is near to current user's current location with `whereKey:   nearGeoPoint:` method.

How can i achieve this?

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
PFQuery *nearbyUserQuery = [PFUser query];
[nearbyUserQuery whereKey:@"currentLocation" nearGeoPoint:userGeoPoint];
// set some sensible limit here
nearbyUserQuery.limit = 10;
```

Then on both `fromRequests` and `toRequests` add an extra constraint on the other user:

```
[fromRequests whereKey@:"toUser" matchesQuery:nearbyUserQuery];
[toRequests whereKey@:"fromUser" matchesQuery:nearbyUserQuery];
```

The rest of your code can remain unchanged.

Comment: wow. i was starting to think there is no way out. and just used `distanceFromLocation` method after fetched `all` friends of user :). this will definitely improve the performance.